# How much approximately the pressure would drop?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, material-science, physical-chemistry

A container made from from aluminium ($0.5~\mathrm{mm}$ thickness $10^3~\mathrm{cm^3}$) closed system , it has 50 psi (nitrogen) pressure inside at temperature $80^\circ~\mathrm C.$

Approximately :

How much pressure will it be lost after 10 years ?
0.1 psi or 1 psi or more ...

I know that Gas permeation through solid is extremely slow and negligible in most cases. It's hard to get general idea without approximate number .

Comment: What is inside the box? If any measurable amount of gas leaks, it will be more if it's hydrogen than if it's, say, isobutane. And what is on the outside -- vacuum?

Comment: inside the box is air

Comment: outside is also air

Comment: Any answer that you get will be unverifiable, unless you are willing to wait 10 years.  If you REALLY need an answer for this, try a radioactive alpha emitter with a relatively short half life, and approximately the same density as the gas you are interested in.  ANY leakage into a larger container will be immediately detectable, and the rate of leakage will give you your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [Fick's second law of diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Fick.27s_second_law), in one dimension, where $u$ is the concentration of the diffusing gas (in $\mathrm{mol/m^3}$) and $D$ the diffusion coefficient:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
If we assume the concentration of gas *outside* the container to be much smaller than inside (a reasonable *assumption*), then the right hand concentration gradient can be determined from Fick's first law to be (with $\tau$ the thickness of the container walls):
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= -\frac{u-u_0}{\tau}$$
Where $u_0$ is the nitrogen concentration outside the box (assumed constant).
With the Ideal Gas law:
$$pV=nRT$$
$$p=\frac{n}{V}RT=uRT$$
$$u=\frac{p}{RT}$$
Also:
$$u_0=\frac{\chi p_a}{RT}$$
Where $p_a$ is atmospheric pressure and $\chi=0.78$ the molar fraction of nitrogen in air.
With those relations and $A$ the total surface area of the container, we get:
$$-\frac{V}{RT}\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{AD}{\tau}\Big(\frac{p}{RT}-\frac{\chi p_a}{RT}\Big)$$
$$-V\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{AD}{\tau}(p-\chi p_a)$$
$$-\frac{dp}{p-\chi p_a}=\frac{AD}{\tau V}dt$$
$$\int_{p_0}^{p(t)}\frac{dp}{p-\chi p_a}=-\frac{AD}{\tau V}\int_0^tdt$$
$$\ln\Bigg(\frac{p(t)-\chi p_a}{p_0-\chi p_a}\Bigg)=-\frac{AD}{\tau V}t$$
We'll call:
$$\alpha=-\frac{AD}{\tau V}$$
$$\implies \Large{p(t)=\chi p_a+(p_0-\chi p_a)e^{-\alpha t}}$$
Note that this expression does not contain $T$. $D$ however is temperature dependent as the following figure shows, for diffusion of gases through solids:

[image: Diffisivity v. temperature]

([Source, page 6](http://web.utk.edu/~prack/mse201/Chapter%205%20Diffusion%20.pdf))

As specific values for aluminium/nitrogen are hard to find we'll use the above values to get a crude estimate. First we need to calculate $\alpha$ from:

$A=600 \times 10^{-4}\mathrm{m^2}$

$D=10^{-12}\mathrm{m^2s^{-1}}$

$\tau=0.5\times 10^{-3}\mathrm{m}$

$V=10^{-3}\mathrm{m^3}$

$\implies \alpha \approx 10^{-7}\mathrm{s^{-1}}$

For 10 years:

$t=10\times365\times24\times60\times60=3.15 \times 10^8\mathrm{s}$

**This puts the *upper estimate* of $-\alpha t \approx -30$ and thus $p(\text{10 years})\approx p_0e^{-30} \approx \chi p_a=11.5\mathrm{psi}$.**

10 years is of course also quite a long time and $0.5\:\mathrm{mm}$ quite thin for a container holding a gas starting at  $5.5\:\mathrm{Bar}$!

Comment: but the temperature $80^\circ~\mathrm C.$ .. should not we use 10^{-16} at least ?

Comment: @user118676: You can use $10^{-16}$, which of course decreases the pressure loss enormously. But most sources I've seen give values of $10^{-12}$ for gas/steel at RT. The graph above is also at higher than 80 C temperature range. W/o a more precise value for $D_{Al,N2}$ it's not possible to give a definitive answer to the question.